# How do I check my upstairs bedroom for insulation in the ceiling?

Tags: insulation

I have a bungalow home in Michigan that has plaster ceiling. How do I check if the ceiling is insulated between ceiling and roof with no access point? The upstairs room was meant to be an attic but converted to a bedroom. Now, in winter it is freezing and in summer extremely hot.

Comment: I just realized that you may mean the angled ceiling of a prior unfinished attic? How do you know it is plaster? I could be drywall... if that is the case you can only open it up to see.

Comment: If you have a loft above the ceiling, there could be a loft insulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the house is old enough to have a plaster ceiling, there is a terrific chance there is no insulation.

You would be wise to cut an access somewhere and get rent a blowing machine for insulation. get about 16" up there. Taper it to the roof rafters so it does not touch the roof. It will allow the roof to get too hot in those places and deteriorate the roof prematurely. 2' of airspace over the insulation is recommended.

Be mindful of any added can (recessed) lights that were put in later, they need to be IC (insulation contact) rated or keep the insulation off them too.

Answer (score 0):

If the attic was converted in the last 50 years or so it's probably drywall rather than plaster.  If you have any light fixtures in the ceiling, there may be a little space between the electrical box and the drywall, and you may be able to see insulation if that's the case.  (Of course you do need to understand how to work safely around electrical etc. to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a FLIR camera that attaches to my iPhone.  It cost around $250 new, and shows where insulation is missing in my apartment.  The camera is expensive for a one-time need (but far cheaper than they used to be), so if you can find a friend who has one to lend, that would save damage and repair.

(I later learned of a competitor for ~$200)